# Aggregate text data of some particular column

Tags: terminology, logic, data-sets

I have a dataset as follows

```
Biodata
last_name  first_name  age   Description     Hobby
Smith       John       20    In high school  Music
Johnson     Robert     45  Software Developer Gardening
Williams    David      15     Junior school  Baseball
Davis       Michael    65     Traveler       Skydiving  
Miller      Molly      25     Scientist      Cycling
```

Now I got a question from a assignment that **Aggregate text data under “Description” and “Hobby”**

I cannot understand what is the meaning of Aggregate text data?

If any one understand the question please share their view point. I want to know it theoretically how could any one aggregate text data depend upon description and Hobby column.

This is a coding assignment of python. But currently I don't bother about coding. I want to know the theoretical meaning of this question and want to solve it manually.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the context where you encountered that phrase?  Have you tried asking whoever wrote it?  Can you provide a full quotation from the assignment, and a link to the original source of the assignment?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/32506/4274, https://stackoverflow.com/q/55858263/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/108580/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that they want you to normalize the text data in those columns.  In other words, you may create a collection of the text, and the two columns would *refer* back to that collection.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm also trying to answer your question without giving too much away. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create two lists,

descriptions = [ ],hobbies = [ ]

Iterate through the rows of data and append the description and hobby for each row to the appropriate lists.

Aggregated data is now stored in the descriptions and hobbies lists